# Why add "()" after closure body in Golang?

Tags: go, closures

I'm reading `The Go Programming Language Specifications` and found myself not truly understand with "()" after closure body:

In `Function literals`:

> func(ch chan int) { ch <- ACK }**(replyChan)**`

In `Defer statements`'s example:

```
// f returns 1
func f() (result int) {
    defer func() {
        result++
    }() // why and how?
    return 0
}
```

I'm not clear about the reason to add & usage of "()" after closure body, hope someone can explain this clearly.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It's not that `()` must be added after (only) a *closure* in `defer`. The language specs for the [defer statement](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements) mandate that its 'Expression' *always* must be a function call.

And why is it so? It's the same as with any other function, in 'defer' or not:

Consider:

```
func f() int { return 42 }
```

and

```
a := f
```

vs

```
b := f()
```

The first expression RHS is a function value. In the second version the RHS is the value *returned by the function* - i.e. a function call.

So is the semantics of:

```
defer f
```

vs

```
defer f()
```

except that the first version doesn't make sense in the context of 'defer', and so the specifications mention that it must be the second form (only).

It's IMHO also easier to learn because of the orthogonality with the above discussed function call outside of the 'defer' statement.

Also note that a function call is not only fn-expr followed by `()`, but an expression list is generally inside the parenthesis (including an empty list). There's a big difference between:

```
for i := range whatever {
        defer func() { fmt. Println(i) }()
}
```

and

```
for i := range whatever {
        defer func(n int) { fmt. Println(n) }(i)
}
```

The first version prints the value of 'i' in the moment when the closure *executes*, the second prints the value of 'i' in the moment when the defer statement *was* executed.

Comment: I got your point, so in `func(ch chan int) { ch <- ACK }(replyChan)`, `func(ch chan int) { ch <- ACK }` means the definition of closure, `(replyChan)` means "execute this closure with parameter `replyChan`".

Comment: Another question with your last example: what's the difference between `in the moment when the closure executes` & `in the moment when the defer statement was executed`? If I have a `return` after `for{}`, both of these 2 `defer`s should execute before `return` at same time, doesn't it?

Comment: I did some experiment about this but still confused about `defer` execution, do you know any article can explain this?

Comment: @ReckHou: I believe the specs (link in the answer) are concise, but complete about the 'defer' statement. I think you are welcome to put another SO question about any details which aren't clear to you.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that in `func(ch chan int) { ch <- ACK }(replyChan)` `ch` and `chan` are the parameters of the function literal, if so why aren't they separated by a comma? Thanks?

Comment: @ReckHou Check out: https://blog.learngoprogramming.com/golang-defer-simplified-77d3b2b817ff

Comment: This last sentence is confusing (maybe incorrect):   Try https://play.golang.org/p/8RBNq0LrUNP and you can see that the second form captures the value of `i` at the point of the defer (because the closure has an `i` argument), while the first form leaves `i` free (no arguments to closure). The first form will print the value  `i` has at the function's end.

Answer (score 22):

If you don't want to read long answers:

```
str := "Alice"
go func(name string) {
    fmt.Println("Your name is", name)
}(str)
```

Is same as:

```
str := "Alice"
f := func(name string) {
    fmt.Println("Your name is", name)
}
go f(str)
```

Answer (score 16):

> References
>
> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Function types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types)
>
> A function type denotes the set of all functions with the same
>   parameter and result types.
>
> ```
> FunctionType   = "func" Signature .
> Signature      = Parameters [ Result ] .
> Result         = Parameters | Type .
> Parameters     = "(" [ ParameterList [ "," ] ] ")" .
> ParameterList  = ParameterDecl { "," ParameterDecl } .
> ParameterDecl  = [ IdentifierList ] [ "..." ] Type .
> ```
>
> [Function declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_declarations)
>
> A function declaration binds an identifier, the function name, to a
>   function.
>
> ```
> FunctionDecl = "func" FunctionName Signature [ Body ] .
> FunctionName = identifier .
> Body         = Block .
> ```
>
> [Function literals](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals)
>
> A function literal represents an anonymous function. It consists of a
>   specification of the function type and a function body.
>
> ```
> FunctionLit = FunctionType Body .
> ```
>
> Function literals are closures: they may refer to variables defined in
>   a surrounding function. Those variables are then shared between the
>   surrounding function and the function literal, and they survive as
>   long as they are accessible.
>
> A function literal can be assigned to a variable or invoked directly.
>
> [Calls](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls)
>
> Given an expression `f` of function type `F`,
>
> ```
> f(a1, a2, … an)
> ```
>
> calls `f` with arguments `a1, a2, … an`.
>
> In a function call, the function value and arguments are evaluated in
>   the usual order. After they are evaluated, the parameters of the call
>   are passed by value to the function and the called function begins
>   execution. The return parameters of the function are passed by value
>   back to the calling function when the function returns.
>
> [Defer statements](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements)
>
> A "`defer`" statement invokes a function whose execution is deferred
>   to the moment the surrounding function returns.
>
> ```
> DeferStmt = "defer" Expression .
> ```
>
> The expression must be a function or method call. Each time the
>   "`defer`" statement executes, the function value and parameters to the
>   call are evaluated as usual and saved anew but the actual function is
>   not invoked. Instead, deferred calls are executed in LIFO order
>   immediately before the surrounding function returns, after the return
>   values, if any, have been evaluated, but before they are returned to
>   the caller.

Since you are still confused, here's another attempt to provide an answer to your question.

In the context of your question, `()` is the function invocation operator.

For example, the function literal

```
func(i int) int { return 42 * i }
```

represents an anonymous function.

The function literal followed by the `()` function invocation operator

```
func(i int) int { return 42 * i }(7)
```

represents an anonymous function which is then invoked directly.

Ordinarily, in a function call, the function value and arguments are evaluated in the usual order. After they are evaluated, the parameters of the call are passed by value to the function and the called function begins execution. The return parameters of the function are passed by value back to the calling function when the function returns.

However, invoking the function through the defer statement is a special case. Each time the "defer" statement executes, the function value and parameters to the call are evaluated as usual and saved anew but the actual function is not invoked. Instead, deferred calls are executed in LIFO order immediately before the surrounding function returns, after the return values, if any, have been evaluated, but before they are returned to the caller.

The defer statement expression must be a function or method call that is invoked directly, not just a function or method literal which is not invoked directly. Therefore, the function or method literal needs to be followed by the `()` function invocation operator so that the defer statement expression is a function or method call.

The defer statement

```
defer func(i int) int { return 42 * i }(7)
```

is valid.

The defer statement

```
defer func(i int) int { return 42 * i }
```

is invalid: `syntax error: argument to go/defer must be function call`.

Answer (score 1):

Without the (), you are not executing the function.

Comment: I have the feeling that someone already mentioned about that. Also, you have enough reputation to just leave a comment.